# How to add layers on mapbox?

Tags: layer, mapbox

I just checked the documentation to add the layer on mapbox. But it is not working for me.

https://www.mapbox.com/help/adding-custom-layers/

Please have a look. 
When I am trying to add a layer it pops up a blank window and there is no provision to add a layer. 
What is the mistake?

Comment: This would need more detail to be diagnosable. If you're trying to get help with mapbox's service and want to have someone look at your account in specific, you can contact support@mapbox.com

Comment: I would loved to help you but I'm not completely sure, as I am looking for the same question. As far as I understand one has to create a layer in TileMill before adding it to Mapbox... If someone can help us by explaining this process will be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the link you provided you will notice the following line.

> A window will open allowing you to add or remove layers to your
>   project. Layers are any .MBTiles you have uploaded to your Data page.

What this implies is that you need to firstly download the "Mapbox Studio" application.

In the app you can then create styles and sources. Its a source you need here. You then have to import some data, after which you can uploaded it to your online account. Afraid i don't now much about this step.

Once you've saved and uploaded this to your account it should then appear in the popup you speak off.

[Download MapBox Studio](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-studio/#darwin)
[View you uploaded data here](https://www.mapbox.com/data/)